# XSLT choose template

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an application written in C# that needs to apply a template name to an xml file that is defined in an XSLT.

Example XML:

```
<Data>
    <Person>
        <Name>bob</Name>
        <Age>43</Age>
    </Person>
    <Thing>
       <Color>Red</Color>
    </Thing>
</Data>
```

Example XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="TargetName" />
    <xsl:param name="RootPath" />

    <xsl:Template Name="AgeGrabber">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Person/Age" />
    </xsl:Template>

    <xsl:Template Name="ColorGrabber">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Color" />
    </xsl:Template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Say I wanted to run the template "ColorGrabber" with path "/Data/Thing" and then run another transform with the template "AgeGrabber" with path "/Data". Is this possible? I was thinking I could pass in the path and the template name (hense the 2 params at the top) and then do some type of switch but it looks like xsl:call-template can not take a parameter as the name attribute.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: What exactly is the expected output from the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a number of issues with this question**:

1. `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  ...` is specified, however, at present >NET doesn't natively support XSLT 2.0.
2. Thecode example is not too meaningful, because a single XML document cannot contain both `/Person/Age` and `/Color` elements -- a wellformed XML document has only a single top element and it can be either `Person` or `Color`, but not both.

**In case there was a more meaningful example**:

```
<Person>
 <Age>27</Age>
 <HairColor>blond</HairColor>
</Person>
```

**one simple solution is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pProperty" select="'Age'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[name()=$pProperty]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, it produces the wanted result:

```
27
```

**In case the nestedness of the elements of interest can be arbitrary and/or we need to do different processing on the different elements**, then an appropriate solution is to use *matching* templates (not named ones):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pProperty" select="'HairColor'"/>

 <xsl:template match="Age">
  <xsl:if test="$pProperty = 'Age'">
    This person is <xsl:value-of select="."/> old.
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="HairColor">
  <xsl:if test="$pProperty = 'HairColor'">
    This person has <xsl:value-of select="."/> hair.
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the correct result is produced**:

```
This person has blond hair.
```

**Finally**,  if you really want to simulate higher-order functions (HOF) in XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, see this answer: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363249/36305** , or learn about **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler: prepare two apply-templates rules (for Age and Color elements) and conditionally send proper node to transform - /*/Person/Age or /*/Thing/Color

Answer (score 0):

You got it backwards. You ought to create templates, matching the nodes you want to use.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:template match="Person|Thing">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <xsl:value-of select="Age" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Thing">
        <xsl:value-of select="Color" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```